# How to prevent response update on Form submission based on cell value in Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I created a Google Form that activates the `onFormSubmit` function every time an answer is entered or modified. I would like to allow the user to change his answer as long as the value in a certain cell changes. When this value is changed, the user can no longer change his response. It can be done?

Here an example:

> TEST FORM (with a single field)
> Expense:

In the connected Sheet i added the field "Approved" like so:

```js
Timestamp           Expense Approved
4/14/2021 14:33:15  400     YES
4/14/2021 14:33:46  200
```

If the user clicks on "edit your response" he can change Expense value.

**Test form**
Your response has been recorded.
*Edit your response*
*Submit another response*

I want that user can't edit his response anymore if Approved field is "YES".

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
x = Cell on which to update if filled in
y = "";
if(x !== y)
//your Code
}
```

Comment: I don't need to block update of a cell, I need to block update of the entire row, without loosing old values. Is there a method to discard row update?

Comment: Maybe just give it the Range of the whole row

Comment: When a user edits his response, changed values will be overwritten. I want to prevent this behaviour if a specific cell value is set to true.

Comment: I am sorry i dont really get what you want to do. If you could explain it different maybe i could help. Some pitures etc would be good

Comment: I can't upload images, but i added an example in my question.

Comment: @MichaelKrapf I believe the op is asking a question in regards to a user who  is attempting to edit their response to a Google Form not a spreadsheet.  onEdit simple trigger only fires on users edits to a spreadsheet not on edits caused by other scripts or formula actions.

Comment: Does this help you? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection

Comment: And just use a if

Comment: The edit is coming from a form submission not a user edit to the spreadsheet

Comment: @MichaelKrapf range protection doesn't lock editing of sheet owner (i.e. script owner)